# Command Line Options for Java Class in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ to run some data analysis classes but I'm not that familiar with Java itself.
Unlike the Java classes that I've run before, this one apparently required some "Config options".

Here's the first few lines of the code:

```
public class CountWorkplaces {
static public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    CommandLineConfigurator cmd = new CommandLineConfigurator(args);
    String inputPath = cmd.getArguments().get(0);
    String outputPath = cmd.getArguments().get(1);

    if (!(cmd.hasOption("population") ^ cmd.hasOption("facilities"))) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

To run the class I specified a `inputPath` followed by an `outputPath` in the "Program arguments" line. I guess `cmd.hasOption` wants me to specify either a `population` or a `facilities` file.

How do I pass on this option? Is there a special syntax for that?

Comment: Just out of curiosity,  `CommandLineConfigurator` Is this a library class or user defined class?

Comment: It appears to be a user defined class, included in the package I was provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide one of these option as program arguments:

`--facilities` or `--population`

example:

```
java Class --facilities inputPath outputPath
```

or
    java Class --population inputPath outputPath